# Ef Core 7 Many-to-Many using strongly typed ids

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to implement a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework (.NET Core 7) using strongly typed ids and am struggling with the configuration.

The follwoing code outlines what I am trying to acheive using a normal naviagtion property for the users roles:

```
public readonly struct UserId
{
  public UserId(Guid value) => Value = value;
  public Guid Value { get; }
}

public readonly struct RoleId
{
  public RoleId(Guid value) => Value = value;
  public Guid Value { get; }
}

public class User
{
  private readonly List<Role> _roles = new();

  public UserId Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public IReadOnlyList<Role> Roles => _roles;

  public void AddRole(Role role)
  {
    _roles.Add(role);
  }
}

public class Role
{
  public RoleId Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DemoContext
  : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(_ => _.Id)
      .HasConversion(v => v.Value, v => new(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(_ => _.Id)
      .HasConversion(v => v.Value, v => new(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasMany(_ => _.Roles)
      .WithMany()
      .UsingEntity("UserRoles",
        l => l.HasOne(typeof(Role)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
        r => r.HasOne(typeof(User)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction));
  }

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=DemoDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
  }
}
```

I am using the follwoing code in a console application to populate the tables:

```
using (var dbContext = new DemoContext())
{
  var role = dbContext.Roles.Add(new Role
  {
    Id = new RoleId(Guid.NewGuid()),
    Name = "System Admin"
  });

  var user = dbContext.Users.Add(new User
  {
    Id = new UserId(Guid.NewGuid()),
    Name = "John Doe"
  });

  user.Entity.AddRole(role.Entity);

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works as expected and the `UserRoles` table is populated with a row linking the user to to role.

I am attempting to acheive the same result using a list of role ids instead of the full blown navigation property.

When I swap out the `User` implemetation with:

```
public class User
{
  private readonly List<RoleId> _roles = new();

  public UserId Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public IReadOnlyList<RoleId> Roles => _roles;

  public void AddRole(Role role)
  {
    _roles.Add(role.Id);
  }
}
```

And modify the configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
  .HasMany<Role>()
  .WithMany()
  .UsingEntity("UserRoles",
    l => l.HasOne(typeof(Role)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
    r => r.HasOne(typeof(User)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction));
```

The `UserRoles` table never get populated with any data when running the console application.

I have implemeted a similar requirement for one-to-many relationships using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasOne<Bar>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(_ => _.BarId);
```

Is there an equivelant for many-to-many relationships in EF Core 7?

**Update**

If possible, I would like to achieve this without explicitly adding a `UserRoles` object like the examples outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-named-join-table).

My sample comes from a project that uses a layered architecture where the `User` and `Role` objects exist in the domain layer, the instantiation occurs in the application layer and the `DbContext` in the persistence layer.

The following code may better represent my requirements:

```
// application layer
var role = new Role
{
  Id = new RoleId(Guid.NewGuid()),
  Name = "System Admin"
};

var user = new User
{
  Id = new UserId(Guid.NewGuid()),
  Name = "John Doe"
};

user.AddRole(role);

// persistence layer
using var dbContext = new DemoContext();

dbContext.Users.Add(user);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I would like to keep my domain objects the same, except changing the User roles property from a list of `Role` to a list of `RoleId`.

Comment: How can you add values to an object that is readonly?

Comment: You can keep you **domain** object model any way you want. But you cannot use it directly as entity **data** model (which is what EF Core entities representing). EF Core Data model has different requirements, one of them being the collection navigation properties to be list of entities, rather than a list of Ids. It doesn't matter if the Ids are  strongly typed or not (i.e. well known CLR primitive value types), they are not entities, hence cannot be used as navigation property. So if you want to follow your "clean" principles, then create a separate data model and map between the two where

Comment: ... where needed. Projections (`Select`) for reading, some sort of a AM `Map` for updating. That's it. EF Core won't adjust to follow your principles, you need to adjust your infrastructure to fit their principles. I've noticed that all DDD people think all others should support their requirements, but that's not the case, and never be, except someone creates D(omain)R(relational)M(apper) framework. EF Core is ORM, which is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework Core 7 with strongly typed IDs and a list of role IDs in the User class, you can modify the configuration and make use of a join entity explicitly. First, create a join entity called UserRole that represents the relationship between User and Role:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public UserId UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public RoleId RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then, update the User class to use a list of RoleId objects:

```
public class User
{
    private readonly List<RoleId> _roleIds = new();

    public UserId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<RoleId> RoleIds => _roleIds;

    public void AddRole(RoleId roleId)
    {
        _roleIds.Add(roleId);
    }
}
```

Next, modify the configuration in OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(_ => _.Id)
        .HasConversion(v => v.Value, v => new UserId(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(_ => _.Id)
        .HasConversion(v => v.Value, v => new RoleId(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

Now, you can update the code in your console application to add role IDs to the user:

```
using (var dbContext = new DemoContext())
{
    var role = dbContext.Roles.Add(new Role
    {
        Id = new RoleId(Guid.NewGuid()),
        Name = "System Admin"
    });

    var user = dbContext.Users.Add(new User
    {
        Id = new UserId(Guid.NewGuid()),
        Name = "John Doe"
    });

    user.Entity.AddRole(role.Entity.Id);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

With these modifications, the many-to-many relationship between User and Role will be established using the UserRole join entity, and the UserRoles table will be populated with the appropriate data.

or you can use [this link](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-core-7-filtering-on-json-arrays?utm_source=csharpdigest&utm_medium&utm_campaign=1658) for more information for how to add a column to user table, and save your roles into this column as a json, and the query it